# JPARepository - delete using date comparison with derived query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use JPARepository in Spring Boot to delete records that are less than a certain date, for for a given userid

Should be something like this `Delete * from [table] where expiration_date < [date] and userid = [userid]`

I thought I should be able to use one of the automatically generated methods

```
    int deleteByExpiryDateBeforeAndUser(Date date, User user);
```

But this is generating a Select and not a Delete.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

*Entity class*

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity(name = "refresh_token")
public class RefreshToken {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String token;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date expiryDate;

    public RefreshToken() {
    }
}
```

*Repository class*

```
@Repository
public interface RefreshTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<RefreshToken, Long> {
    Optional<RefreshToken> findByToken(String token);

     @Modifying
    void deleteByUserIdAndExpiryDateBefore(Long userId, Date expiryDate);

    int deleteByUser(User user);
}
```

Here's how I'm calling it

```
 @Transactional
 public void deleteExpiredTokens(User user) {
        refreshTokenRepository.deleteByUserIdAndExpiryDateBefore(user.getId(), new Date());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see a select statement because Spring Data first loads entities by condition.

Then once entities became 'managed' Spring Data issues a delete query for each entity that was found.

If you want to avoid redundant SQL query - you have to consider `@Query` annotation.

Then your code will look like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface RefreshTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<RefreshToken, Long> {
    // ...
  
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM refresh_token WHERE user_id =:userId AND expiry_date < :expiryDate", nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying
    void deleteByUserIdAndExpiryDateBefore(Long userId, Date expiryDate);

    //...
}
```

Comment: I don't mind so much the double query, but I don't see where it's deleting.  I just see the select statement being executed.  Should I be seeing the individual Deletes?

Comment: Yes, in case you have entities that match the condition you have after `deleteBy`.

Comment: Thanks, it works.  Not sure why it didn't seem to be working yesterday.  Probably my mistake, because I was thrown off by seeing the select